# saving properties in SharePoint Managed metadata

Tags: 2013, 2010, office-365, managed-metadata, 2016

I need to have a department list available across site collections

So I used Managed Meta data and created a list of Departments in it.

Now I want to have a Department Director field tagged to each department

How can I achieve it?
if it not advisable or not possible, what is the alternate way to have Department & Department Director (people field) accessible across site collections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by making use of custom properties.

They are traditionally used to capture additional metadata for each Term.

See below screenshot.

[image]

To retrieve the value of the these custom properties, you can follow the below links:

Using JSOM - [Get customProperties of Term in Manage Metadata SharePoint 2013 by Client Object Model](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/55b46124-02cf-4d7d-8920-696a42540244/get-customproperties-of-term-in-manage-metadata-sharepoint-2013-by-client-object-model?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Using CSOM - [Get SharePoint Term Custom Properties using C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/46990005-3704-4970-8aa8-4e967df78223/get-sharepoint-term-custom-properties-using-c-client-side-object-model?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Comment: is there anyway to display these in a modern list, without custom code? Similar to a lookup's extended properties (LookupField:ID, LookupField:Title)